Set Click event for Panel which dynamicly created
I made a class which builds some cards(Panel), and I want to add "Click" event while they are generated. I use the code below:
private void CoverBuilder(Panel mainPanel, Grid grid, int x, int y, int gameId, string 
imageAddress, string exeAddress, string title)
{
   card = new GameCard(grid.GameCardWidth, grid.GameCardHeight, grid.GameCardCoverWidth, grid.GameCardCoverHeight, Image.FromFile(imageAddress), title, gameId);

   Panel gameCard = card.Make();
   gameCard.Location = new Point(x, y);
   gameCard.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
   gameCard.Click += GameCard_Click;
   mainPanel.Controls.Add(gameCard);
}

private void GameCard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel gameCard = (Panel)sender;
    StartGame(int.Parse(gameCard.Name));
}

private void StartGame(int gameId)
{
    DataTable table = gameDB.Find(gameId);
    string exeFileAddress = table.Rows[0]["ExeAddress"].ToString();

    // start exe process
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(exeFileAddress)
    {
        UseShellExecute = true
    };
    Process.Start(psi);
}

But when I use them in a form and click on them, they do not work.

Ensure GameCard_Click is properly attached to the Click event.
Ensure gameCard.Name is correctly set.
Check if the Click event is firing correctly.

Have you set a breakpoint in the event handler, to see what happens there? It's not clear what card.Make() is doing (is the Name Property set correctly?), why card is defined elsewhere or why you have set UseShellExecute = true when it appears you're trying to launch an executable using its path (the Shell shouldn't be involved)

You already have the event handler for the panel click event, put the line below above the event handler:
this.GameCard.Click += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.GameCard_Click);
This will allow the event handler to fire when the panel is clicked.
